# How to store the output of a binary file in database

Tags: php, binary

I am executing a file from terminal of linux (ubuntu). The file is a binary file with .out extension. The file is executed and it gives an output on the terminal itself. Now i want to store that output  in the database.
How can i store this value?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PDO and [bindParam](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Example code:

```
$yourCmdOutput = `path/to/your/cmd --some-args`;

$pdo = new PDO("your configuration");
$cmd = $pdo->prepare("INSERT ... VALUES (?)");
$cmd->bindParam(1, $yourCmdOutput);
$cmd->execute();
```